# Ввод данных. Помогиииите

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int(input())
for i in range(a):
print(chr(int(input())),end="")
```

как сделать так, чтобы в третьей строке данные входили через пробел?

Comment: Заменить `end=""` на `end=" "`? Что-то как-то ничего не понятно

Comment: @andreymal не-а. Посмотрите ответ Zhihar'a — будет понятно, а то я тоже сначала так подумал. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor что-то ответ Zhihar'а слишком сильно отличается от кода в этом вопросе, боюсь он не угадал

Answer (score 2):

какие именно данные?

если числа:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

если строки, то

```
arr = input().split()
```